# Can jenkins deploy model solution to azure analysis service?

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-analysis-services

I have a .asdatabase file that is model solution. My objective is to use jenkins to automatically upload it to azure analysis service. From what can I find, it's mostly client-based. Is there anyway to make it run on jenkins by using command?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is use Automation in Azure. Use Jenkins to use POST to webhook as created by automation runbook.